# PK Pass not updated in Wallet app on pull to refresh

Tags: ios, objective-c, passbook, passkit

I have successfully added pass via Mail to wallet. I see the Pass in the Wallet app, but I'm unable to see updated pass when I pull to refresh at backside of the pass. Here are logs:

```
passd[119] <Warning>: Verifying structure and signature for pass pass.com.test.pass/‎1
passd[119] <Warning>: Signature validation: succeeded
passd[119] <Warning>: Generating POST request with URL <my_https_url/api/PassRegistration/v1/devices/70e435342e38df4e4346e779c6dff6e3/registrations/pass.com.test.pass/%25E2%2580%258E1>
passd[119] <Warning>: Request contains header field <Authorization: ApplePass my_token>
passd[119] <Warning>: Request contains body dictionary {
        pushToken = 93b5d5cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_similar;
    }
passd[119] <Warning>: Register task (for device 70e435342e38df4e4346e779c6dff6e3, pass type pass.com.test.pass, serial number ‎1; with web service url my_https_url/api/PassRegistration/) got response with code 201

passd[119] <Warning>: Generating GET request with URL <my_https_url/api/PassRegistration/v1/devices/70e435342e38df4e4346e779c6dff6e3/registrations/pass.com.test.pass>
passd[119] <Warning>: Get serial #s task (for device 70e435342e38df4e4346e779c6dff6e3, pass type pass.com.test.pass, last updated (null); with web service url my_https_url/api/PassRegistration/) got response with code 200
passd[119] <Warning>: Get serial numbers task completed with update tag 1459943482, serial numbers (
        1
    )
passd[119] <Warning>: Get pass task (pass type pass.com.test.pass, serial number ‎1, if-modified-since (null); with web service url my_https_urlapi/PassRegistration/) got response with code 200
passd[119] <Warning>: Verifying structure and signature for pass pass.com.test.pass/1
passd[119] <Warning>: Signature validation: succeeded
passd[119] <Warning>: Get pass task (pass type pass.com.test.pass, serial number ‎1, if-modified-since (null); with web service url my_https_url/api/PassRegistration/) encountered error: Requested serial number ‎1, received serial number 1
passd[119] <Warning>: Get pass task (pass type pass.com.test.pass, serial number ‎1, if-modified-since (null); with web service url my_https_url/api/PassRegistration/) will retry after 60 seconds
```

Some portion of my pass looks like this:

```
 "storeCard": {
    "headerFields": [
      {
        "key": "lessons",
        "label": "Points",
        "value": "200"
      }
    ],
```

On update web service call, I passed same pass in binary format but with points value to 500. Expected output is to show Points as 500 instead of 200. I see the *"Couldn't update pass"* message once refreshing is done. I am testing in iPhone4s with IOS 9.2.1.

I referred: https://github.com/yuchaoonline/ytoo.service/blob/master/dotnet-passbook-master/Passbook.Sample.Web/Controllers/PassRegistrationController.cs

The method `BinaryFormatter()` didn't work so I changed to `BinaryMediaTypeFormatter()` as per reference from https://github.com/horizon-institute/AffectiveComputingCloud/blob/master/AffectiveComputingCloud/RestAPIWebRole/Formatter/BinaryMediaTypeFormatter.cs

I tried with following header parameters:

```
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.apple.pkpass");
response.Content.Headers.LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "pass.pkpass";
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name = "pass.pkpass";
```

Comment: The last statement of the console output tells me that your web service is not responding with a new .pkpass bundle. When you say "responded with binary format", what are you sending in response to that final call?

Comment: I am responding generatedPass byte array as: response.Content = new ObjectContent<Byte[]>(generatedPass, new BinaryMediaTypeFormatter());

Comment: How are you setting headers? - what is your content-type?

Comment: I think it is application/octet-stream based on this statement: SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));

Comment: As per the documentation: application/vnd.apple.

Comment: I got the log of Signature validation: succeeded. It seem, pkpass is received by device and signature in the pkpass is validated, but there is failure in updating the UI of pass. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Finally, I fixed issue by regenerating new passes, installing and refreshing. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems multiple issues like wrong content-type. Changing content type to `application/vnd.apple.pkpass` and passing updated pass with updated date fixed the issue.

Comment: can you list out what all was wrong.. or share the code of api-controller which did the updateS?